# GitHub GPG key can't find in PyCharm but works in Mac Terminal

Tags: git, pycharm, gpg-signature

I followed the guide to setup GPG key and managed to make a signing commit via mac terminal. However, when I tried to do the same in PyCharm, if i do `git commit -m "test gpg key"`, it gave me an error in PyCharm terminal:

```
error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I'm new to GPG key, where can I start to investigate and can someone advise why it works in mac terminal but not in PyCharm? Thanks.

Comment: It's telling you that pgp is not installed

Comment: Given that `gpg` runs from your terminal but not from PyCharm, it's probably some kind of path issue. How does PyCharm manage its `$PATH` setting? Where does it get the initial setting?